# 2-fold cv vs. validation set

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, validation

Will 2-fold CV be the same as the validation set approach? To me it seems that the answer is no, since a 2-fold CV will go through the data set 2 times, while the validation set only will do the procedure once.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no.  In cross validation, each set takes a turn being the "validation" set.  In a 2 fold CV, there would be 2 such sets, so there would be two validation sets.

Comment: It is however the same in the sense that it is the "validation" approach repeated multiple times to decrease variance through averaging